# How to get the length of a field in TADOQuery?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

For example, I can get the value of a certain field. But is it possible to find out the length of the field?

```
MyQuery.Fields[0].Value; // contains the value of the field
```

Comment: It's not necessary to put information in the title that you can put in the tags, such as "Delphi 7". The tag system here works extremely well, and doesn't need any help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields size can be taken from Field.Size, if this Value is 0 Size it's a fixed type you use Field.Datasize.

Short example:

```
uses TypInfo;

Procedure DisplayFieldInfos(DS:TDataset;List:TStrings);
var
 i:Integer;
 Function GetSize(F:Tfield):Integer;
  begin
    Result := F.Size;
    if Result=0 then Result := F.DataSize;
  end;
begin
  for I := 0 to DS.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin  // display Fieldname [Datatype] : Size
        List.Add(Format('%s [%s] :  %d',
                [
                DS.Fields[i].FieldName,
                GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TFieldType), integer(DS.Fields[i].Datatype)),
                GetSize(DS.Fields[i])
                ]));
      end;
end;

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DisplayFieldInfos(ADS,Memo1.Lines)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
ADOQuery1.FieldDefList.FieldDefs[0].Size
```

And see if that gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: It is possible MySQL is not giving the length information to the TADOQuery. If it is returned from MySQL that is where I believe it should be. I don't have Delphi 7 to try this. See my other answer for a work around.

Comment: @MikhailRybkin: `TField.Size` returns `0` if the `Field.DataType` isn't one of a certain type. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TField.Size) lists the types that return something other than `0` (the doc link is for Delphi XE3, but the list is pretty much the same, and you can find the equivalent list in the D7 help).

Answer (score 0):

You can query the information from MySQL directly

```
SELECT column_name, column_type, character_maximum_length 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '...'
  AND table_schema = '...'
```

Just provide the `table_name` and `table_schema` and it will return all the columns and their length (at least the length for the string columns).

Comment: How do I find out the table schema for my table?

Comment: No, I don't think this is going to work. Because what I'd like to get is only the length of the fields which the query returns.

Comment: This is a separate query you would need to run to get the lengths. You could possibly do a join with your other table and return the lengths as an additional column.

Comment: Jim, pick an answer and post it. You can edit your original answer to provide more information; there's no need to post multiple answers. These aren't the EMBT forums - editing is allowed here. :-)

Comment: @Ken, I provided two alternative different answers. That is the reason SO allows posting multiple answers.

Comment: No prob. This one technically is wrong, because it doesn't answer the question about retrieving it from `ADOQuery.Fields` as the question asks. (It's running a separate query to retrieve the info. Not downvoting as wrong, BTW; just mentioning.) As an alternative that doesn't address the question asked, I would have mentioned it as such in the other answer, but that's just me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked with me:

```
My_Query.Close;
My_Query.SQL.Text :='select * From My_Table';
My_Query.Open;

Edit1.Text:= IntToStr(My_Query.FieldByName('My_Field').Size);
```